# VBA & SQL create password prompt

Tags: oracle, excel, vba

I'm trying to have my code ask the user for Oracle SQL credentials. My code works as intended as long as i write the User ID and Password into the code, but I am not able to create a login prompt. Obviously, I'd rather not store the User ID and password in plain text.

I believe that the line "conn.Properties("Prompt") = adPromptAlways" should activate a prompt, but i get the following error:

Run-time error '3220':
Supplied provider is different from the one already in use.

I can't figure out how to fix the provider issue, or how to correct my code. Any ideas or sources on how to fix this?

```
Sub MySub()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sConnString As String
Dim SqlText As String
Dim R As Range

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long

Dim MyFileName As String
Dim WB As Workbook, TempWB As Workbook

Set WB = Workbooks("Error_cases.xlsm")
Set ws2 = WB.Sheets("Input_file")
Set WS = Sheets("Errors")

Sheets("Errors").UsedRange.ClearContents
Sheets("Input_file").UsedRange.ClearContents

' Create the connection string.
sConnString = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=myDataSource;User Id=;Password=;"

' Create the Connection and Recordset objects.
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset


 For Each R In Sheets("SQL").Range("A1:A1")
  SqlText = SqlText & R.Text
Next R


' Open the connection and execute.
conn.Properties("Prompt") = adPromptAlways
conn.Open sConnString
Set rs = conn.Execute(SqlText)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution, answering my own question in case anyone else encounters a similar problem. Apparently having the provider only in the connection string caused the issue, this was fixed by setting it separately before adding the prompt property

```
' Create the connection string.
sConnString = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;Data Source=myDataSource;

' Create the Connection and Recordset objects.
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Provider = "OraOLEDB.Oracle"
conn.Properties("Prompt") = adPromptAlways
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
```